# How Dependency Injection by name works in Spring @Bean method parameters

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I understand Spring DI and how it works in general.

But what I cannot understand here is in case of `@Bean` method parameter injection, how spring knows about the parameter name so it could inject beans from its bean's factory based on the parameter's name?

For example, In the following example, the methods `fernas1` and `fernas2` parameters are being wiped at runtime. however, spring still can inject the correct `Abbas` bean instance into it.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    @Autowired
    private Abbas abbas1;    // this is understandable, hence the field name is available at runtime

    @Autowired
    private Abbas abbas2;   // this is understandable, hence the field name is available at runtime

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        Map<String, Fernas> beansOfType = ctx.getBeansOfType(Fernas.class);
        System.out.println(beansOfType);

        Arrays.stream(DemoApplication.class.getMethods())
                .filter(m -> m.getName().startsWith("fernas"))
                .flatMap(m -> Stream.of(m.getParameters()))
                .map(Parameter::getName)
                .forEach(System.out::println);

        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(DemoApplication.class).abbas1);
        System.out.println(ctx.getBean(DemoApplication.class).abbas2);
    }

    class Abbas {
        String name;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name;
        }
    }

    class Fernas {
        Abbas abbas;

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return abbas.toString();
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public Abbas abbas1() {
        Abbas abbas = new Abbas();
        abbas.name = "abbas1";
        return abbas;
    }

    @Bean
    public Abbas abbas2() {
        Abbas abbas = new Abbas();
        abbas.name = "abbas2";
        return abbas;
    }

    // this is not understandable, hence the parameter name is NOT available at runtime
    @Bean
    public Fernas fernas1(Abbas abbas1) {
        Fernas fernas1 = new Fernas();
        fernas1.abbas = abbas1;
        return fernas1;
    }

    // this is not understandable, hence the parameter name is NOT available at runtime
    @Bean
    public Fernas fernas2(Abbas abbas2) {
        Fernas fernas2 = new Fernas();
        fernas2.abbas = abbas2;
        return fernas2;
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**  The same problem and solution by @Javier both works on `method` and `constructor` parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If parameter name reflection is not available, it uses the information in the class file itself. See [DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/DefaultParameterNameDiscoverer.html)

> Default implementation of the ParameterNameDiscoverer strategy
>   interface, using the Java 8 standard reflection mechanism (if
>   available), and falling back to the ASM-based
>   LocalVariableTableParameterNameDiscoverer for checking debug
>   information in the class file.

For instance, the LocalVariableTable of `DemoApplication.fernas2` is

```
    Start  Length  Slot  Name   Signature
        0      16     0  this   Lcom/example/demo/DemoApplication;
        0      16     1 abbas2   Lcom/example/demo/DemoApplication$Abbas;
        9       7     2 fernas2   Lcom/example/demo/DemoApplication$Fernas;
```